# Mat Table Child Module Not Filtering String Passed from Parent Module

Tags: angular, filter, angular-material, mat-table

Relevant portions of parent module, List Component:

```
...
 searchKey: string;
 listComponent: IList;


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.listComponent = new RequestListComponent(this.service);
  }
  public doFilter() {
    this.listComponent.doFilter(this.searchKey.trim().toLowerCase());
  }
```

Relevant HTML for ListComponent:

```
<mat-form-field class="side-by-side" id="filter">
  <input matInput name="filter" [(ngModel)]="searchKey" (keyup)="doFilter()" placeholder="Search Text" autocomplete="off">
</mat-form-field>
```

The child component is of type IList, the list interface. This interface is created successfully, shows data, data is sortable, but filtering does not work.

Relevant portions of child component, request-list:

```
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private service: RequestTableService) { 
  this.displayedColumns = this.service.ColumnsToDisplay(RequestType.STATUS);  }
  }

 ngOnInit(){
  this.service.getTable(RequestType.STATUS, this.active).subscribe(res =>{
  this.dataSource.data = res as StatusRequest[];
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.tableFilter(); 
});

 refreshTable(){
  this.service.getTable(RequestType.STATUS, this.active).subscribe(res =>{
  this.dataSource.data = res as StatusRequest[];     
  });
 }

 public doFilter(value: string){
    this.dataSource.filter = value;
 }

  tableFilter(): (data: any, filter: string) => boolean {
    let filterFunction = function(data, filter): boolean{
      return data.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1;
    }
    return filterFunction;
  }
```

Data Service:

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getTable(selectedRequestType: string, active: boolean):Observable<any> {    
    let params = this.getParamsByUserRole(active);    
    return this.http.get(this.getRouteByRole(selectedRequestType), {params});
  }
```

I don't think request-list.html is relevant.

Logging value of doFilter() to console works as it should, displaying the value of the string from the matInput, which sets the searchKey string in the parent module.

I feel like this is related to the filterPredicate but I'm a typescript noob and don't know why.

Edit: The problem is that the datasource.data array is empty or even null, depending on how it's initialized. Is the problem in my data service? Updated code to reflect how data is returned. To be clear, the table fills with data after the service.getTable() call in ngOnInit.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the this line, do you hit it? `return data.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1;`

Comment: Also you know that your 'data' object in your filter function is of type StatusRequest and not a string right?  I think that may be why your filter doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @KyleAnderson - I can't get VS_Code to hit any breakpoint. That said, console logging before the filterFunction is seen, but in the filterFunction is not. So why wouldn't we enter the function? 
RE: data - ahh...right. I changed this to data.CatalogNumber so that when we do enter the filter function, it should filter on this column.

Comment: Huh, I'm out of ideas then.  I figured the data issue was the problem.  I have a very similar setup to yours and it works so I can't see anything that's missing.

Comment: @KyleAnderson - edited my post.

Comment: The service call looks fine to me.  Is your backend actually returning data?  Also you said your table data was actually showing up on the page?  That shouldn't happen if your dataSource.data is empty

Comment: The table is fetched at ngOnInit, and does indeed return data. Pagination and sort is set at this time (which works). When declaring datasource, if I do not instantiate with "new," when we try to filter, the datasource is null. This doesn't make sense to me. It's as if there are two threads - one where the data resides, and one where the filtering is done and they are not accessing the same variable instance.